# Entity Framework 4 Code First Inheritance Solution via Reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, inheritance, ef-code-first

I've found several solutions to this issue, some that don't work and some that violate the DRY principle.

I want to have all of my entities inherit from `Audit` (which provides the properties/columns `IsActive`, `CreateDate`, `UpdateDate`, `CreateUser`, & `UpdateUser`). I can get that to work fine, but that creates an issue with the column names that are generated with relationships (`CreateUser_UserId` & `UpdateUser_UserId`). I'd much prefer `CreateUserId` and `UpdateUserId`. Unfortunately, `ColumnAttribute` doesn't seem to work like articles/SO answers have suggested. However, the Fluent API does work. It just violates DRY in that every single entity I create, I end up having to do something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    // have to write these two lines for each new entity I create
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.CreateUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.CreateUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasOptional(u => u.UpdateUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.UpdateUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

So, I want to use reflection to just loop through every single type that extends `Audit` and effectively call those method chains on my modelBuilder. This is how far I got from searching around before I got completely stumped:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    var types = GetTypesInheritingFrom(typeof (Audit)); // implementation unimportant
    foreach (var t in types) {
        var method = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity");
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t);
        var o = generic.Invoke(modelBuilder, null);
        // not sure how to proceed from here, HasOptional() requires an Expression<Func<t, TTargetEntity>>
        // not sure if WithMany() is actually required??
        // not sure what to do with HasForeignKey() either, it requires an Expression<Func<User, Guid>>
    }
}
```

This is basically the first real thing I've done in C#/.Net and it feels really complex to me. If I'm going about this the completely wrong way, please give me an alternative that doesn't make work for me. I don't really like the idea of a T4 template or an Interface - that's repeated code I'd rather not have to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create helper method:

```
private void MapUserRelations<TEntity>(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    where TEntity : Audit
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().HasOptional(u => u.CreateUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.CreateUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<TEntity>().HasOptional(u => u.UpdateUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(u => u.UpdateUserId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false); 
}
```

and use your reflection:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    var types = GetTypesInheritingFrom(typeof (Audit)); 
    foreach (var t in types) 
    {
        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("MapUserRelations");
        var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(t, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        generic.Invoke(this, new Object[] { modelBuilder });
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I made `MapUserRelations` `static`, changed the `BindingFlags` accordingly, and refactored the body of `OnModelCreating` out to another static method (as I figure I'll be adding more to the body of `OnModelCreating`). I don't know if this should be a separate question - how can I make `"MapUserRelations"` compile safe?

Comment: @Olson: Badly. Reflection is not compile safe.

Comment: What is "Badly." in reference to? By compile safe, I meant like.. is there any syntax I can do to effectively generate the string `"MapUserRelations"`? Something like (pseudo-syntax) `MyClass.MapUserRelations.ToString()`...?

Answer (score 2):

Is Audit entity itself? If yes, you can apply those rules directly on Audit.

I also think using inheritance is bad. I would use complex type property instead. See:
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx

And why do you want to change the way the DB schema is generated. Especialy using code first, this should be hidden. Only reason I see for changing this is when you already have DB schema and want to create your mapping for it.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. No, `Audit` is not an entity itself. I skimmed that article you linked to - while a complex type would be nice (and I may change my model to use one), I'd still end up with less than ideal column names. I want to change the way the schema is generated because people (myself included) are going to have to manually touch on those columns, whether I like it or not (some things are just easier on the database layer). Plus it'll be easier/more consistent to override how they display in the UI.